# SSD not showing in Disk Management / File Explorer

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-8.1, sata

I have an SSD which is not showing up as a drive in Windows (8.1)

- It doesn't show up in Disk Management
- It doesn't show up in File Explorer
- It doesn't show up in Device Manager.
- It *does* show in the BIOS.
- It passes a DPS Self-Test in the BIOS.
- Another computer boots successfully from it.
- A test with another SSD has the same results

This is a drive that I've been using to build a Windows image on another device, and need to connect it to a PC to create a backup. So I connected a spare SSD power and Data cable from my PC to it. I've done this quite a number of times so I thought I had damaged or loosened the cables with all the plugging in and out. However the same cables work fine for the PC's main HDD (If I swap the cables, my PC still boots and the SSD is not found). Then I thought I had possibly damaged the SSD itself. However, the device I'm using to create the image loads fine from it.

What could be wrong here? Why would Windows not see an SSD if the BIOS could?

**Edit**

The SSD is a 2.5inch, 250 GB SATA drive.
Model is: Crucial MX500

Comment: SSD is a vague description. If I was you I would post more details.

Comment: @r2d3 i've updated

Comment: Have you tried a different SATA cable?

Comment: @Ramhound - I've tried swapping SATA cables between the SSD and the main HDD and the same thing happens, i.e. Windows boots from the HDD and doesn't show the SSD. I also managed to find a spare SATA data cable lying around - I tried that too, but still no joy

Comment: Is it possible that the PSU is too weak/weakened to support a second drive?

Comment: do you have any M.2 storage installed? for some disk controllers, using M.2 slots may disable some of the sata interfaces on the board. I'd be surprised then that the bios can see it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to uninstall "Standard SATA AHCI Controller" in the Device Manager, then reboot the machine.

With thanks to...

https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ssd-showing-in-bios-but-not-disk-management-or-device-manager.2928703/